# iphone, tableView and appStore application

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, app-store

I want to create an application excacly like appStore.
A nice table (I have the source code from apple using custom table cell)
But my main problem is that I cannot find a nice tutorial or a guide on how to make the product detail page.
I want to have a label at the top then a text and after that I want to have the images.
I notice that in appStore when you reach the images it locks there for a while!
How can I do that???
I tried using a UIScrollView but I believe this is not the case.
I am thinking using tableView again with custom cells but again I am not sure.
Any ideas? or any good working example? or tutorial?
thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

start from here:

http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284

Which will teach you basic table design skills and how to create custom cells with images on the left.

Then if you would like to learn how to create a tab bar application an be able to have a navigation controller at the top then you can follow this descriptive tutorial step by step to achieve this.

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/44897

What do you get after following these two tutorials?
the appStore application, well not exactly but you will get your own version.

**EDIT: Added Details page how to achieve appStore like UIScrollView effect.**

follow this brilliant video tutorial.

http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-ipad-appstore-like-uiscrollview-with-paging-and-preview/

Have fun

**PK**
Then

Comment: Well my main problem is the details page of the product! So if you know a nice tutorial about the details page that will complete the appStore application I want to do :)

Comment: ah ok. ive edited my post. and you can now check out the video an di believe thats what you want. check the first 5 seconds of the video and you will see what i mean notice how the image gets locked once in focus until the user goes to the next image which is again locked once in focus. The tutorial will show you how to achieve this. Start from fresh.

Comment: OK we are actually there! But again how will I make the detail page. I mean how will I combine the textview with the uiscollview this is what I really want. :)

Comment: you have a UIView, with a text view and the uiscroll view on there.